# Images in CSS file(main.css) don't load with Flask

Tags: python, html, css, flask

My folder layout is:

```
/env
   app.py
/env/static/styles
   main.css
/env/static/img
   contains all the image
/env/templates
   index.html
```

My main.css contains:

```
#background_section_top {
width: 100%;
height:88px;
background: url(static/img/background_section_top_bg.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

My index.html contains:
`<link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/main.css') }}">`

But I couldn't see the image in my index.html. Could you please help where I'm doing mistake? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify

```
background: url(static/img/background_section_top_bg.jpg);
```

to

```
background: url(/static/img/background_section_top_bg.jpg);
```